# Make checkout country dropdown readonly in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, readonly, country

I want country dropdown on woocommerce as readonly. [image: Country Image]

I already set the default country to australia but I want them to be readonly.

Answer (score 8):

The answer of Kashalo is correct… You can also use one of this multiple other ways:

1) For Checkout Billing country only:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readdonly_billing_country_select_field');
function readdonly_billing_country_select_field( $fields ) {
    // Set billing and shipping country to AU
    WC()->customer->set_billing_country('AU');
    // Make billing country field read only
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}
```

2) For Checkout and My account Billing country only:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'readdonly_billing_country_select_field');
function readdonly_billing_country_select_field( $fields ) {
    // Set billing and shipping country to AU
    WC()->customer->set_billing_country('AU');
    // Make billing country field read only
    $fields['billing_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}
```

3 For Checkout billing and shipping country:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readdonly_country_select_field');
function readdonly_country_select_field( $fields ) {
    // Set billing and shipping country to AU
    WC()->customer->set_billing_country('AU');
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('AU');
    // Make billing and shipping country field read only
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}
```

4) For Checkout and My account billing and shipping country:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'readdonly_country_select_field');
function readdonly_country_select_field( $fields ) {
    // Set billing and shipping country to AU
    WC()->customer->set_billing_country('AU');
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('AU');
    // Make country field read only
    $fields['country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Very much..Everything is working very well

Comment: Your code makes the fields disabled. Since disabled fields are not available in form, checkout throws validation error. Is there anything i have to add inorder to fix this other than `kashalo`s answer ?

Answer (score 7):

you can use `woocommerce_form_field_args` to add disabled attribute to the quntry select field.

add the following code to your `functions.php` and you will get the desired result.

```
add_action('woocommerce_form_field_args', 'disable_country_dropdown', 10, 3);


function disable_country_dropdown($args, $key, $value)
{
    if ($key == 'billing_country') {
        $args['custom_attributes'] = [
            'disabled' => 'disabled',
        ];
    }
    return $args;
}
```

the issue when we puted the select drowpdown disabled the option value is not passed when you click place order and in order to solve this issue we can add hidden field with our desired value as follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'billing_country_hidden_field');

function billing_country_hidden_field($checkout)
{

    echo '<input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="billing_country"  value="PL">';

}
```

just change the `value="PL"` to your country code value and everything will work as expected.

**OutPut :**

[image]

Code is tested with StorrFront Theme.

Comment: Nice catch, I was trying early to make it work with ['custom_attributes'] = array( 'readonly' => 'readonly' ) … but "disabled" is the correct way for a select field.

Comment: @kashalo It's working but the problem now is that the country which is by default in australia can't proceed to checkout...It say here "Billing Country is a required field.
Please enter an address to continue."

Comment: let me double check it and get back to u

Comment: @pinkwidowbaby i updated my answer with solution for the issue please check

Answer (score 0):

```
/*CHECKOUT BILLING ADDRESS READ ONLY*/
  add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
        function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();;
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;
            foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
                if($key == 'billing_company' || $key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2' || $key == 'billing_city' || $key == 'billing_postcode' || $key == 'billing_phone' || $key == 'invoice_email' || $key == 'purchase_order' || $key == 'ship_to_first_name' || $key == 'ship_to_last_name'){
                    $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
                    if( strlen($key_value)>0){
                        $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
                    }
                }
            }
            return $checkout_fields;
        }


if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   // your code for logged in user 
   add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readdonly_billing_country_select_field');
function readdonly_billing_country_select_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readdonly_billing_state_select_field');
function readdonly_billing_state_select_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );   
    
        return $fields;
}
    
} else {
   // your code for logged out user 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).