# Disable billing_state field check out page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, field, checkout

I managed to disable every single check out field in my WooCommerce webshop but only "billing_state" doesn't work for some strange reason.

These are the hooks I am using

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields' );
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';

    return $fields;
}
```

I allready tried the billing_country field too because this is also a select field and maybe it has something to do with that but on the billing_country field the code is working fine.

Anyone had an idea why this function doesn’t work on my billing_state field in de checkout? Maybe something to do with conditional logic because State is not always visible with all the countries you can select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try like this and set default country before making it disabled. You can not disabled the required field without any value.You should set the country as well for the dropdown, And for more clarification you can follow the link [Make checkout country dropdown readonly in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279966/make-checkout-country-dropdown-readonly-in-woocommerce)

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readdonly_country_select_field');
    function readdonly_country_select_field( $fields ) {
        // Set billing and shipping state to AU
        WC()->customer->set_billing_state('state');
       
        // Make billing and shipping country field read only
        $fields['billing']['billing_state']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );
        
    
        return $fields;
    }`
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. so please follow the link for your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279966/make-checkout-country-dropdown-readonly-in-woocommerce

Comment: thank you for you answer and the link but also with these functions I am not able the disable the billing_state field... I can disable every field except that one:(